# Calculating the amount of time passed between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written some JavaScript to calculate the difference between two dates, from a twitter stream, and then equate that to a specific value - such as 'Seconds ago', 'x days ago'.....

I've created a Fiddle here that demonstrates what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/meAEe/3/

However the result is always equal to '0 days ago'.

Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Please post your code within the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `else` between every `if` statement.

Right now it will go into every `if` statement following the first that matches. If the time is less than an hour it's also less than two hours, less than a day, less than two days, and less than a year. Each one will replace the previous one, so you only see the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic error in your code. The last if statement will always execute because you have not connected your if statements using `else if`, which will result in the program execution dropping out once one of the conditions matches.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. If you look into your code

```
                    var rightNow = new Date("Wed, 21 Dec 2011 13:05:09 +0000");
                var then = new Date("Tue, 20 Dec 2011 19:05:09 +0000");
```

difference is less than 24 hrs and giving 0 days.

I have put

```
var then = new Date("Mon, 19 Dec 2011 19:05:09 +0000");
```

It given 1 day ago

Comment: The result is correct, but it's not the wanted result. If the difference is less than a whole day it should be displayed with lower resolution, like hours or minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to chage the `if`s to `else if`s (except the first one, of course). Right now they are all evaluated every time.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from some programming details, your problem lies in using `Math.floor` function.

According to: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp

Math.floor actually returns the nearest **integer**, which in this case is 0, because the results is 0.75.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do this: `Math.floor(diff / day);`
The result of `diff / day` is `0.75`. If you round that down, it's `0`. If you change the date, you'll see that your code works just fine.